# Send email to different web domains automatically

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2013, email-validation, email-client

I have created registration page which will send automatically email users to confirm their account. Is there any way to send conformations emails to different domains like hotmail,yahoo,live,etc.. all different domains(including .com,.uk,.org, etc..,). If so can i get code/article to how to use the code/modify my code in c#.. Here is my code for sending email.

```
 using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@mydomain.com", txtEmail.Text))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
        string body = "Hello " + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + ",";
        body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
        body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("CS.aspx", "CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "password");
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
```

Comment: There is no issue, you can send to any mail account.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything different to send to different email domains.

Comment: To expand on what @DLeh said, your code references 'gmail' because it is sending from a Gmail address, but you can send it to anyone you like. The code with `smtp` stuff in it is just saying you are using Gmail's smtp servers to send the email.